# TITLE VALIDATION in JavaScript for REGEXP which can take alphanumeric and can take Special char [, / ( ) & - : . space]

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

For my website , i need a REGEXP in java script  for validation TITLE which can take alphabates, digits and Special char set [, / ( ) & - : . space], but if any user enter only single and double spaces or single or double .. like [..] in title  or double digit [1 2] then it's should not allowed, atlest one aplhabate is required. please help

Comment: What have you tried? show some of your own efforts, before asking others to write your code for you. If you can't write regex, then [follow the tutorial on this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: -1 Failed to show any attempt at solving this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
^[-a-z0-9,/()&:. ]*[a-z][-a-z0-9,/()&:. ]*$
```

This will match any number of your special characters followed by a Latin letter, followed by number of your special characters. It's effectively equivalent to `[-a-z0-9,/()&:. ]+` except it requires at least one `[a-z]` somewhere in the string.

Of course, you need to escape the `\` when written as a regex literal in javascript, and you probably want to use the `i` flag for case-insensitive matching:

```
var pattern = /^[-a-z0-9,\/()&:. ]*[a-z][-a-z0-9,\/()&:. ]*$/i
```

Comment: It's not working well, I need like EX:- '  ' is not allowed or 'Aa123' should be allowed and '&& ' is not allowed

Comment: @ShrikantGupta I forgot to include `0-9` in the outer classes. See my updated answer.

Comment: Invalid regular expression: /^[A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z0-9./&()\-,: ]*{1,128}$/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: If you also want to check the length of the string, I'd recommend just checking `.length`.